# Configurable products showing out of stock in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I tried to add configurable products to magento.

Everything works fine. But in frontend catalog there is a tag showing "Out of stock".

But I have saved

- Manage Stock as Yes
- Enable Qty Increments as No
- Stock Availability as In Stock

What is the problem?

Comment: You need to assign children / associated prodcuts, and make sure they are in stock. the stock levels are taken from each variation/child rather than the cofigurable product itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check the child products of the configurable product are inStock. If at least one  child product is out of stock, this can cause to your problem.

Comment: i have set all child products inventory's Manage Stock as No. but it shows out of stock. but when i show one of the child product in website the tag gone. I do not want to show the child products in web site

Comment: I have found the solution.Previuosly I didnt add child products in Main Website it must be added in main website and visibility set to Not Visible Individually :)

Answer (score 3):

have you add associated products for Configurable product ? and please check associated product are in stock..because Configurable product are dependent on associated products.,,